# Why won't the listener handle keyup event after I cancel the submit event?

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault;
});
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    handleSubmit();
  }
});
```

I cancel the submit event, but I want `handleSubmit` to be invoked on `enter` `keyup`. However when I run the page, type some stuff into the form, and press `enter`, nothing happens. I've tried using a different `keyCode` and listening to the form's `keyup` event instead, but couldn't fix it. I don't want to use the click event.

Edit: I solved it. See my answer.

Comment: When you press enter, it triggers the submit event. So what you can do is prevent the form from being submitted onSubmit but invoke your `handleSubmit` function.

Comment: Have you verified that the submit is canceled? `window.preventDefault;` does nothing because you do not call that function (it should be `window.preventDefault();`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  handleSubmit();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

The reason I had to invoke `preventDefault` was because my web host would always refresh the page after submitting the form, which I did not want.

Answer (score 0):

plz check this, I think the `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` should on the `keydown` event

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    handleSubmit();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```